# Missing integer in an array

Tags: algorithm

Given an list of positive integer , find the smallest integer which is not in the list .

**For Example:** list=[7,4,9,1], the answer would be 2.

What should be the fastest algorithm ( Without Sorting) to calculate the smallest integer not in the list ?

Note list of integer very large , so hashing not possible ?

Comment: Apart if you have very serious performance requirements, a bubble sort followed by an iteration should be fast enough. Note that a performance comparison would probably be dependant on the typical array size and integer values.

Comment: Why not sorting ? You can sort in place. Is the array read only ?

Comment: @dystroy Or if you're in an interview...

Comment: @dystroy Any algorithm better than O(n*lgn) ?

Comment: Do you have an idea of the missing values ? If they're small (like in [0..1000]), then it's easy.

Comment: @dystroy Integer value range from 1 to 10^9 ?

Comment: I still think you can't get faster than O(n*log(n)) without further knowledge of the number in question

Comment: 1) allocate a 10^9 bool array and initialize it to false 2) iterave over your source array and put true for the seen numbers 3) profit

Comment: @all someone has downvote all my question which i has asked on stackoverflow .. WHY ??????????/

Comment: you could probably write to the support

Comment: @sp1rs [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Answer (score 0):

**O(n*log(n))**

The easiest algorithm which runs in O(n*log(n)) would be:

- Sort the array with Quicksort which is O(n*log(n))
- Iterate through array and find smallest element which is not in the list which is maximal O(n)

**O(n) and O(1) extra space**

There exists an algorithm running in O(n).
It works as follows:

- Iterate through your array. For every positive number i you set the value at array[i] to -1. Ignore values greater than the size of the array
- Iterate a second time through the array and find the first index which is not negative. (O(n))

Comment: Won't work if the positive number `i` is larger then the array?

Comment: @sp1rs I don't see any way of getting better than O(n). Since even with hashing you'd need to hash every value (which is again O(n)) and you'd require extra space (also O(n)). Therefore I wouldn't consider hashing for better performance

Comment: @LukasHäfliger I'm saying the method your are saying is a kind of hashing . and hashing will not work .

Comment: @sp1rs could you please clearify what you want? If you have 10^9 numbers, this algorithm will use 4GB of memory. Could you clearify why hashing will not work? This algorithm will use approximately 5*n + n assembly instructions. I don't see where you'd want to save code

Comment: I don't think the O(n) solution will work. Assuming a zero-indexed array, what if you have `[2,3,1]`. If you start off setting `array[2] = -1`, then you will lose the `1` value, so you'll conclude that that's the smallest value not there.

Comment: @LukasHäfliger I think your O(n) is correct but need some modification. Instead of changing array[i] to -1 change it to         -array[i] .

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, I would

1. sort the array (choose the relevant sort depending on your typical arrays or use an adaptative sorting function)
2. iterate over the array to find the first missing integer

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are **unique** you can use a binary search in O(nlogn). The missing value is at most n.

- Set low = 0, high = n,
- Set a = low + (high-low)/2
- Count values between low and high smaller or equal to a

  - if it's less then half, repeat for high = a
- Count values  between low and high greater than a

  - if it's less than half repeat for low = a
- Else no solution (all values are in the array)

Comment: shouldn't the array be sorted for this method?

Comment: Not if you loop over the entire array each time. That's why it's O(nlogn) and not O(logn)

Comment: why is this better than just sorting and iterating? And for an algorithm in O(n) see my answer

Comment: Surely in the last case the solution would be (the largest value in the list)+1 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Mark arr[i] as visited by making arr[arr[i] - 1] negative. Note that 
// 1 is subtracted because index start from 0 and positive numbers start from 1
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if(abs(arr[i]) - 1 < size && arr[abs(arr[i]) - 1] > 0)
      arr[abs(arr[i]) - 1] = -arr[abs(arr[i]) - 1];
}

// Return the first index value at which is positive
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    if (arr[i] > 0)
      return i+1;  // 1 is added becuase indexes start from 0
}
```

2 Step Algorithm to find smallest positive missing element from array

1. We traverse the array containing all positive numbers and to mark presence of an element x, we change the sign of value at index x to negative. If x>size then ignore x.
2. We traverse the array again and print the first index which has positive value. (Remember, it will be index+1 as array starts from 0th index)

`Time: O(n)`
`Space: O(1)`